# I sent BCC from exodus to a BTC address

Tags: wallet

I just made a huge mistake,i sent my claimed BCC from my Exodus wallet to my  BTC.com wallet .oops .Can i get them back ? The transaction has been passed OK on the block chain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to reverse a bitcoin transaction. Transactions on the bitcoin network are designed to be permanent and irreversible.

You can use a [Bitcoin Cash blockchain explorer](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20cash) to see where the BCC now resides by checking the address you sent from and to.

Answer (score 0):

You can still claim your BCC if btc.com supports BCC.
Here's what you need to do

1. Export your BTC private key(s) from Exodus
2. Import your BTC private key(s) into your BCH wallet on BTC.com

This [recover BCC sent to BTC address](http://support.exodus.io/article/156-ive-sent-bitcoin-cash-to-my-bitcoin-address) might be more helpful